# Is there some way to save a mysql columns value in a python var?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I'm trying to save a column value into a python variable; I query my DB for a int in a columns called id_mType and id_meter depending of a value that I get from a XML. To test it I do the next (I'm new using databases):

```
m = 'R1'
id_cont1 = 'LGZ0019800712'
xdb = cursor.execute("SELECT id_mType FROM mType WHERE m_symbol = %s", m)
xdb1 = cursor.execute("select id_meter from meter where nombre = %s", 
id_cont1)

print (xdb)
print (xdb1)
```

I get every time the value "1" where the id_mType for 'R1' = 3 and id_meter= 7 for id_cont1 value. I need this to insert in another table (where there are both FK: id_meter and id_mType. Dont know if there is an easiest way)

Comment: Hello, I think you should check out the package pandas if you are not already familiar with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store it in a list. Is that okay?

```
results=cursor.fetchall()
my_list=[]
for result in results:
    my_list.append(result[0])
```

Now `my_list` should hold the `SQL` column you get returned with your query.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `fetchone()` method to fetch a row from a cursor.

```
row = xdb.fetchone()
if row:
    mtype = row[0]
row = xdb1.fetchone()
if row:
    meter = row[0]
```